# forkJoin is deprecated for multiple observable function

Tags: angular, angular10, fork-join

First I have multiple services files like that =>

services1.ts

```
Patch(updateobject:object,id:number): Observable<MyObject> {    
    return this.http.patch<MyObject>(`${this.MyObject_API}/${id}`,  JSON.stringify(updateobject),{headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})           
   }
```

services2.ts

```
Patch(updateobject:object2,id:number): Observable<MyObject> {    
    return this.http.patch<MyObject>(`${this.MyObject2_API}/${id}`,  JSON.stringify(updateobject),{headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})           
   }
```

I tried like=>

```
forkJoin(service1.patch(),service2.patch()).subscribe(([call1response,call2response])....
```

but why `forkJoin` is strikethrough and show `forkJoin` is deprecated?

message=>

```
(v1: ObservableInput<MyObject>, v2: ObservableInput<MyObject>): Observable<[MyObject, MyObject]>' is deprecated
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use an array as argument:

```
forkJoin([service1.patch(),service2.patch()]).subscribe(([call1response,call2response])....
```